# .htaccess Rewrite internal paths

Tags: php, .htaccess, silverstripe

I want to run an existing SilverStripe installation local. Only problem is that the "require_once" path's are hardcoded:

```
/www/htdocs/FOLDER/http/blog/_config.php
```

I want to change them all to my local path without changing them in the code:

```
C:\wamp\www\FOLDER
```

Is this possible to do with htaccess?

Comment: Hmm, maybe you may create link C:\www\htdocs to C:\wamp\www? (sorry I'm not Windows guy, so no idea how to do it technically).

Comment: Ok, looks like Vista and up have `mklink` command to do so, so it may be 'quick and dirty' solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. In .htaccess you may rewrite urls, not PHP constructs.

Comment: Tnx, are there any other way's to achieve this?

Comment: Without code rewrite... I can't find any solution right now. Maybe you should consider rewriting by replacing `/www/htdocs/...` with relative paths? This way you won't need to worry about differences between local and remote versions.

Comment: Oke, that was an option I wanted to avoid :)